# bower installs several files. why and how can I change it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bower

I am using bower to install dependencies for my project(I know there is yeoman but I am using bower). After setting up component.json file, when I do bower install it installs dependencies to correct directory but it install lots of other unnecessary files with it too. Now I want bower to install the specific file which is needed for example `jquery.js, backbone.js and underscore.js` and nothing else. **How can I do it with bower?**

Comment: I agree, I don't want my production environment littered with unnecessary files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to the package authors to specify what files to exclude from the package using the [`ignore`](https://github.com/twitter/bower#defining-a-package) property. For now just include the files you want in the your app/website and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 18):

I recently [wrote up a possible solution](http://joshbranchaud.com/blog/2014/02/19/Managing-Single-Files-With-Bower.html) to this problem and will highlight the main points below.

If you know you want a specific file from a particular package, it is easy enough to tell bower to only grab that file. For instance, with `normalize.css`, the only file that I care about is, well, `normalize.css`. So instead of typing:

```
bower install --save normalize-css
```

I can be more specific and tell bower to just download the `css` file:

```
bower install --save https://raw.github.com/necolas/normalize.css/master/normalize.css
```

That, of course, will always grab the latest version of normalize from the repository's master branch when `bower install` is invoked for your project. If, however, I want to make sure I always get the `3.0.0` version of normalize, then I can dig through the releases/history to find the appropriate URL and viola:

```
bower install --save http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.0/normalize.css
```

Comment: Maybe this doesn't bother anyone else - but, whose idea was it to have Bower install large portions of GitHub to your server, most of which is never touched by the developer, and not provide a clean API to install production-only files? At least provide the option.

Comment: @tfmontague Bower doesn't make assumptions about what you want to download. It is up to each package developer to create a clean branch without all the fluff. Unfortunately, many developers leave all the extra stuff lying around the same branch that Bower is pulling from.

Comment: Good point but you should give sample with jQuery which obviously doesn't work. How are you suppose to know the full url when the purpose of using bower in the first place is to create a quick download, I can as well use 'Save As' from the direct full url on my browser.

Offfhh ... technology sometimes

Answer (score 7):

You can check out [bower-installer](https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer).

`bower list --path` usually tells about the main js file in the package, which `bower-installer` conveniently picks up and exports only those files to your asset directories. You can then use this directory instead and ignore the `bower_components` dir.