# Dealing with all the extra stuff created by Bower

Tags: bower, bower-install

I'm confused about the proper way to use Bower. When I install components I get a large `bower_components` directory that contains much more than just the files I am interested in. For example, if you install jQuery with bower you get a ton of source files.

I only want to keep the files that are absolutely needed in my project to run. Is there a general solution for getting rid of the unneeded files copied down by bower? How do I know what to get rid of? Why are these even there?

Of course, if even if I do delete them, the next time I run `bower install` they will all come back.

What the deal here? How are you supposed to manage this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several answers to this question already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129503/bower-installs-several-files-why-and-how-can-i-change-it). My opinion is that you just use the files you need and leave the rest as they were. You're not checking in the `/bower_components` folder with version control anyway so the only harm done is using up a tiny bit of disk space (for example: jQuery installed from Bower is a 2,2MB folder in total).

Edit: I found a grunt plugin called [grunt-bower-task](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task) that let's you fine-tune your bower installs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Grunt you can check out [grunt-preen](https://github.com/BradDenver/grunt-preen) and [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep). First one will clean your bower_components folder, second will wire those 'important' files from installed packages directly to your index.html.

Comment: Note that you should not preen the bower.json files of your dependencies, as these are used by wiredep. Running wiredep first is also an option. (btw, [preen](https://github.com/braddenver/preen#gulp-task) + [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#gulpjs) also work great with [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/))

Comment: (also note: running wiredep first and then runnig preen to also delete the bower.json files would require a `bower update` before each run)